# Bootstrap 3 - rearranging divs within columns in a custom way on collapse

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is sort of difficult to explain, so please refer to the visual aids below.

Current Desktop Version -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdNp4.png

Current Mobile Version -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjddY.png

> **Desired Mobile Version -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hxxl.png**

JSBin -> http://jsbin.com/wisurozilo/1/edit?output

I'm not sure of the best way to do this as I am a PHP/MySQL developer and this defintely requires client-side expertise. Any suggestions on how I can get the Desired Mobile Version?

There is no requirement to combine the divs within one column, just that they collapse in a way that is presented in the desired fashion.

Comment: Have you ever looked into flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @NunoCalaim I have not heard of flexbox. This is pretty cool! Are you sure I can apply this to my situation? At first glance it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use jQuery to rearrange the content when the "breakpoint" is hit. I used this script to detect when a specific breakpoints are hit > https://github.com/cakebake/jquery-breakpoint-check and I used the following jQuery to to move elements to different parents

```
(function($){
    $.fn.moveTo = function(selector){
        return this.each(function(){
            var cl = $(this).clone();
            $(cl).appendTo(selector);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a working example: http://jsbin.com/cihuhe/edit?output

Answer (score 0):

There is [built in feature](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) in bootstrap 3 for column ordering using `pull` and `push`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! However, it's not the columns I'm trying to reoder. There are divs within the columns that need to be rearranged. Take a look at the visual aids they are a pretty good depiction of what I'm going for. Also the JSBin code should help.

Comment: Then why the title of the post is `collapsing columns in a custom way` ?

Comment: My mistake. Changing title.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put element 1, 3, 5 in the same `<div class="row">` and 2, 4, 6 in another row. You can use col-?-? feature in bootstrap to spread out the element into desired width. Elements in the same row would be stacked first before another row in mobile.

Comment: Right, but that means that the heighest point of section "2, 4, and 6" would only appear after the lowest point of section "1, 3 and 5" when the page is -not- collapsed. This would not work for my example because each section will not have the same size, and it -must- appear as the visual aid shows for the Current Desktop Version.

Comment: You might have to try using webkit-transformation at different screensize if you want to be exact. Easy way would be to just break the blocks up into more pieces and align but what you are building might not allow you to do that.